# Herkunft von »bis in die Puppen«

Tags: etymology

Meine Frau hat eine aus Deutschland stammende Arbeitskollegin (ich glaube aus der Nähe von Dresden), und von ihr hat sie Redewendung *»bis in die Puppen«* übernommen:

> Ich habe gestern **bis in die Puppen** ferngesehen.
>   Morgen werde ich wieder **bis in die Puppen** arbeiten müssen.

Gemeint ist:

> Ich habe gestern *bis spät in die Nacht* ferngesehen.
>   Morgen werde ich wieder *bis spätabends* arbeiten müssen.

Mich verwirrt diese Redewendung jedesmal wenn ich sie höre, denn ich habe sie bisher hier in Österreich sonst noch nie gehört. Was hat *»etwas bis spätabends machen«* mit Puppen zu tun? Woher kommt diese Redewendung?

Zusatzfrage:
In welchen Regionen ist diese Redewendung gebräuchlich?

Comment: Wörterbuch für deutsche redensarten ist hier hilfreich: https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=puppen&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_varianten_ou

Comment: In welcher Quelle hast du gesucht und bist nicht fündig geworden? ;)

Comment: Hier in Hannover hört man diese Redewendung zwar nicht jeden Tag, aber ich hab hier noch keinen kennen gelernt, der gesagt hat, dass er sie nicht kennt.

Comment: @Anion. Das klingt nach einer interessanten Untersuchung. Fragst du Leute explizit danach?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann nein. Man hört diese Redewendung ja manchmal von anderen (oder benutzt sie auch selbst), und darauf hab ich noch nie sinngemäß ein "Was bedeutet das?" von irgendjemandem gehört. Das wäre im Gedächtnis geblieben.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Laut dem online [Redensartenindex](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=puppen&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_varianten_ou) verhält es sich so:

> umgangssprachlich, salopp; Diese Redensart ist in Berlin entstanden
>   und bezieht sich auf den so genannten Großen Stern, einen Platz im
>   Berliner Tiergarten. Dieser wurde im 18. Jahrhundert mit Statuen
>   antiker Götter geschmückt, die im Volksmund "Puppen" genannt wurden.
>   Bis zu diesen Puppen zu spazieren, war damals ein beliebter langer
>   Sonntagsausflug. Wie sehr häufig entwickelte sich dann aus der
>   ursprünglich räumlichen Dimension der Länge eines Weges ein Begriff
>   für die Länge eines Zeitabschnitts.

Die Prepositionswahl, ***in*** statt ***zu***, fällt mir aber auf.

Comment: DWDS adds: "doch fehlt für diese Erklärung der Beweis". https://www.dwds.de/wb/Puppe

Comment: Unklar, wie aus "zu den Puppen" ein "in die Puppen" geworden sein soll und außerdem, wie lang zu spät. Kommt mir sehr windig vor. Dann würde ich schon eher denken, dass ein Zshg. mit "verpuppen" besteht (was die Raupe macht).

Comment: Ich finde die oben zitierte Erklärung mit antiken Statuen in Berlin auch zweifelhaft. Klingt zu konstruiert. Wäre es vielleicht eine gute Idee, einmal in Ausdrücken aus dem Hebräischen nachzuforschen? Viele seltsame Redewendungen im Deutschen erklären sich ja durch eine Verballhornung einst gängiger hebräischer Wörter. "Bis in die Puppen" klingt mir wie ein guter Kandidat für so eine Herkunft.

Comment: "In die Erdbeeren", "in dem / zum Zirkus", "in den Tiergarten" etc. ist nicht gänzlich abzugrenzen von "zu", vgl auch "zu Geld kommen", Eng "come into money", "go to the zoo". Über die Glaubhaftigkeit sollte man sich nicht auslassen, wenn man gar keine Ahnung von der Mundart hat, die zudem schon in die Jahre gekommen ist. Soll heißen, die Bsp. sind generell und nicht auf den Fall bezogen, sowie "in/zum Tiergarten" heute zumindest einen geringen Unterschied für die Mehrheit der Sprecher darstellen möge.